# Rails 3.1, How to exclude authorize resource for devise controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I need to do some thing like that:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    authorize_resource :unless => :devise_controller?
...
```

But, if I try to click on sign-up link, I get:

```
NameError in Devise::SessionsController#new

uninitialized constant Session
```

How can I skip authorize_resource for all the actions of devise_controller ? or any class that inherits devise_controller ?

What if there are many controllers to exclude ?

Any help will be more than appreciated, I don't need to pass an instance, just the class name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :authenticate_user!


  # Don't let controllers get away with 
  # any monkey business
  check_authorization :unless => :devise_controller?

end
```

and it works for me and I am using CANCAN with rails 3.2